# AngularJS $watch not working for pagination, giving undefined error

Tags: angularjs

I'm a new bee in the angularjs world. I was trying to use some pagination logic in my code.

While using $watch, my app is throwing `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on $watch

```
  .controller("EmployeeListCtrl", ["employeeResource", EmployeeListCtrl]);

  function EmployeeListCtrl(employeeResource) {
      var Empdata = this;
      Empdata.employeePerPage = [];

      employeeResource.query(function(data){
          Empdata.employee = data;          
      });

      Empdata.currentPage = 1;
      Empdata.numPerPage = 10;
      Empdata.maxSize = 5;

      Empdata.numPages = function() {
          return Math.ceil(Empdata.employee.length / Empdata.numPerPage);
      };

      Empdata.$watch('Empdata.currentPage + Empdata.numPerPage', function() {
          var start = ((Empdata.currentPage - 1) * Empdata.numPerPage),
              end   =  start + Empdata.numPerPage;
          Empdata.employeePerPage = Empdata.employee.slice(begin, end);   

      });
  }
```

and since I'm using *controller as* I didn't use the $scope, maybe that would be the case ?

Are there any opinions on using $scope vs *controller as*
and since we on this
what is recommendation 
$scope or controller as

Answer (score 0):

`$watch` is a method of `$scope` so that's your problem. Solution is to inject `$scope` so you can use the `$watch` function on your object. See this question and answer: [Angularjs: 'controller as syntax' and $watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078535/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-and-watch)

Answer (score 0):

`Empdata` is not an Angular object, it has no `$watch` method.  You need to make it a property of the controller's `$scope`.

```
$scope.Empdata = {};
$scope.$watch('Empdata.currentPage + Empdata.numPerPage', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use $watch when using `controller as` then you need explicitly bind this variable to scope using `angular.bind`

**CODE**

```
 $scope.$watch(angular.bind(Empdata, function () {
    return 'Empdata.currentPage + Empdata.numPerPage'; 
  }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // now we will pickup changes to newVal and oldVal
  });
```

Thanks