# How can we watch expressions inside a controller in angular 1.4 using angular-new-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

Since **we cannot inject `$scope` inside controllers** in Angular 1.4+, how can we watch expressions the way we used to do with `$scope.$watch`?

An attempt to inject `$scope` can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/yegowi/1/edit?html,js,output) ("Could not instantiate controller" error), and tutorials tells us that:

> Angular wont be able to instantiate the controller if we pass $scope
>   in it. It defines its observable properties on this.
>   ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/891436/Introduction-to-Basics-of-Angular-newRouter))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: 'controller as syntax' and $watch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078535/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-and-watch)

Comment: You still can inject `$scope`.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You most certainly can inject $scope.

Comment: I can't inject `$scope`, I get an error if I try. http://jsbin.com/yegowi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: what error did you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this and needed an npm package; no good having everyone on the team build from source for the time being. We released an interim package on npm that fixes this issue: `npm install loomio-angular-router@0.5.7`

**Note**: you may need to **rename ng-viewport to ng-outlet** to get the interim package working.

Comment: There is also an issue with $componentLoaderProvider, how can I resolve it?  Unknown provider: $componentLoaderProvider

Answer (score 2):

I have just found out that there is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/router/issues/313) on ngNewRouter causing this problem. It [has been fixed](https://github.com/angular/router/commit/5a2441f2eea9e59949abdb7f484c8981d2aec7d2), but haven't been released yet.

To workaround it, try this:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:angular/router.git
$ cd router
$ npm install
$ gulp angularify
```

after that, copy the dist files to your project

Comment: If you get `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` run `git clone https://github.com/angular/router` instead

Comment: `gulp angularify` outputs `No gulpfile found` !

Answer (score 2):

you have $watch available in .activate. Check bellow (copy paste from my app).

```
function accountHistoryController (authService, accountFactory, CONSTANTS, $q, $routeParams) {

}
accountHistoryController.prototype.canActivate = function() {
    return !!this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
accountHistoryController.prototype.activate = function($scope) {
    console.log ($scope);
    $scope.$watch('_this.currentPage', function(newPage){
    if (newPage == undefined) return;

});

}
```