# Angular new router Inject $scope to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How i can use $scope to gain access to functions likes $watch, $emit, $digest?

When i am trying to do this:

```
class HomeController {
  // @ngInject
  constructor($scope) {
    $scope.country = {};
    $scope.countries = [
      {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
      {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'},
      {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
      {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'},
      {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'},
      {name: 'Andorra', code: 'AD'},
      {name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'},
      {name: 'Anguilla', code: 'AI'}
    ];
  }
}

export default HomeController;
```

I am getting an error:
**Could not instantiate controller HomeController**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue when attempting to use $watch for data binding.

At this time of writing, the current version of Angular New Router (v0.5.3) could not instantiate controller with $scope injected. The [issue](https://github.com/angular/router/issues/313) was logged on github.

According to a separate thread, there is an interim package on npm with the fix of this issue. Check out [zVictor's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30215177/4904267) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**NEWER ANSWER**
With the new router the controller gets initiated **before** the child scope is being created.
The child scope (the controller's scope) is created when the `activate` method is being called - that is - after the actual compilation of the view is finished. Therefore, it is simple impossible the inject $scope - it is simple created later.
*Long story made short...*
There is a **better**, built-in **solution** for this.

Instead of assigning your properties to the non-existing-yet `$scope`, simply assign them on the `"this"` variable - the controller instance variable. Then on the view, you can use them by referring the controller name:

```
angular.module('app.home').controller('HomeController', HomeController);

function HomeController() {
    this.name = "tomer";
}
```

And now on the template html:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{home.name}}
</div>
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Well, how would you use $watch with this then?