# AngularJS new router could not instantiate controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am trying to create a service to use throughout my Angular app that pulls in data from a .json file using `$http`. This is what the factory looks like:

```
var trooNewsServices = angular.module('trooNewsServices', []);

trooNewsServices.factory('Articles', ['$http',
  function($http){
    $http.get('resources/articles.json').success(function(data) {
          return data;
    });
  }]);
```

I passed in the `trooNewsServices` dependency into my module declaration. Any controller that I try to pass in my new `Articles` service, I get a

> "Could not instantiate controller HomeController"

error in the console. Not sure what I am missing/what is wrong with this code. Should I be using `$resource` instead of `$http`?

Here is how I am passing the 'trooNewsServices' into my main module:

```
var TrooNews = angular
    .module('TrooNews', ['ngMaterial', 'ngNewRouter', 'trooNewsServices'])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider
            .theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('indigo')
            .accentPalette('pink');
    })
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: false,
            requireBase: false
        });
    });
```

Here is how I try to inject 'Articles' into one of my controllers:

```
TrooNews.controller('HomeController', ['Articles', 
    function(Articles) {
        this.name = 'Troo News';
        this.articles = Articles.query();
    }]);
```

And here is how I set up routing in my 'AppController':

```
TrooNews.controller('AppController', function($router, $mdSidenav, $mdToast, $parse, $http) {
    $router.config([{
        path: '/',
        component: 'home'
    }, {
        path: '/home',
        component: 'home'
    }, {
        path: '/about',
        component: 'about'
    }, {
        path: '/settings',
        component: 'settings'
    }, {
        path: '/article/:id',
        component: 'article'
    }]);

    this.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
        $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
    };

    this.navigateTo = function(link) {
        var parts = link.match(/^(.+?)(?:\((.*)\))?$/);
        var url;
        if (parts[2]) {
            url = '.' + $router.generate(parts[1], $parse(parts[2])());
        } else {
            url = '.' + $router.generate(parts[1]);
        }

        $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().content('Navigate To: ' + url).position('bottom right'));
        $router.navigate(url);
        this.toggleSidenav('left');
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you're passing the service to a controller?

Comment: @tymeJV - updated to show that!

Comment: @FuzzyTree I changed .success to .then and got the same exact error

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `HomeController`, you are executing `this.articles = Articles.query();`, but your `Articles` service doesn't define any `query` function.

Instead, your service is just immediately executing an HTTP GET request upon creation. Not sure why this would lead to your error, but it is a red flag.

Try changing your `Articles` service to the following:

```
trooNewsServices.factory('Articles', ['$http',
  function Articles($http){
    this.query = function() {
      return $http.get('resources/articles.json')
        .then(function(response) { return response.data; });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This makes sense. But, after changing my Articles service to this I still get the "Could not instantiate controller HomeController", (this also gets thrown in a different controller that uses Articles but doesn't use query) and the error is associated with the router.es5.js file - so maybe there is something wrong with the routing that is messing with the service injection?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error message under different conditions.  In my case, it was because I was referencing $scope in my dependencies (old habit that I'm trying to break).  In my case, I wasn't using $scope and could easily remove the reference.  That cleared up my error.  Check your code for $scope references and see if that fixes it.

https://github.com/angular/router/issues/313

and

[How can we watch expressions inside a controller in angular 1.4 using angular-new-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167898/how-can-we-watch-expressions-inside-a-controller-in-angular-1-4-using-angular-ne#)