# Using $scope.$watch in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having some issues using $scope.$watch in an ES6 project. The watch fires once and then never again.

Here's the code:

```
export class SomeController {
  constructor($log, $scope) {
    'ngInject'
    this.watched = 1;
    $scope.$watch('watched',(nv,ov)=>{
        $log(nv); //only fires once
    });
   }
  otherMethods(){}...
}
```

Specifically I am using this generator: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

Comment: To clarify: Te equivalent ES5 code works just fine? Or what makes you think that this an issue with ES6 specifically?

Comment: Do you change the value of `watched` somewhere in order to fire the event ? could you provide you html code ? and/or a fiddle ?

Comment: I know that the variable is updating as I can do {{someController.variable}}

Thanks for the downvotes guys, really constructive.

Comment: There is literally no other code to this problem, the watch just doesn't fire.

Comment: I beleive it's ES6 as usually $scope.$watch works, however here I'm not binding to the scope firectly, I'm binding everything to the this of the constructor. It could be a ui-router issue I suppose...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$scope.$watch(() => this.watched, function (nv, ov) {
  console.log(nv);
});
```

as explained more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078535/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-and-watch).

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/kut341oa/) with a demo.

And also, the event fires on `$digest` cycles on :

- DOM events (user changing value of an input field, clicking on a button to invoke a JavaScript function and so on)
- XHR responses firing callbacks
- Browser's location changes
- Timers (setTimout, setInterval) firing the callbacks

or if you call it explicitly.

Comment: yeah you're right.. I was just trying to underline the fact that with the code given, it shouldn't fire more than once. I'll update my answer

Comment: Brill, this explains my problem! Thanks :)